# Jasper ireport 3.7.6 font style not rendering in PDF

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using ireport 3.7.6 and trying to use different fonts for the different text elements. I made the necessary changes to the font style and is showing up when I do the preview but, the PDF produced by the java application only gets the default font. i checked the XML and it has the **fontName="Times New Roman"** . Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of jasper report 5,6 different fonts are included through [font extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/).

You need a .ttf version of the font you like to display (Times new roman can be found in windows / font).

The easiest way to include a font is through [ireport-designer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer) or [Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension)

1. Obtain desired ttf font.
2. Install the font in ireport or studio
3. Export the font extension (this creates a .jar)
4. Add the jar to your classpath.

This is a link for these step [iReport](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-fonts) and this in [Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension)

Answer (score 0):

try to set jasperreports.properties like this:

```
# http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html
# http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html
#
#    net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name=SansSerif - the default font name.
#    net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size=10 - the default font size.
#    net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name=Helvetica - the default PDF font.
#    net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=Cp1252 - the default PDF character encoding.
#    net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded=false - by default PDF fonts are not embedded
#
net.sf.jasperreports.export.character.encoding=UTF-8
net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name=DejaVu Sans
net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size=10
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name=DejaVu Sans
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=UTF-8
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded=true
```

jasperreports_extension.properties:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.myfamily=com/your/company/resources/fonts/jasper.xml
```

and map your pdf-fonts to phisical fonts (jasper.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<fontFamilies>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
        <!--
        <locales>
            <locale>en_US</locale>
            <locale>de_DE</locale>
        </locales>
        -->
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Serif">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans Mono">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <!--
        Mapping Java logical fonts, for the sake of HTML export only.
    -->

    <fontFamily name="SansSerif">
            <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
    <fontFamily name="Serif">
            <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
    <fontFamily name="Monospaced">
            <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

</fontFamilies>
```

and desired fonts to resource directory , put jasperreports.jar jasperreports-fonts.jar jasperreports-javaflow.jar to classpath

I tested this on Linux, WinXp, Win7. Rendering and export works fine

Comment: Am I suppose to add the properties under tools->option->Jasper Report Properties? if so is the value same? and where am suppose to add the extension? I am kinda new to ireport.

Comment: this will work only in ireport studio, but you can not to embed your reports to your app for good rendering pdf. for using in standalone app, set thous *.properties in top dir of your jar

Comment: I am using ireport Designer. will this work in it too?

Comment: not sure. this settings for correct rendering pdf out of app