# export ireport to pdf with specific character font

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to export a ireport-5.6.0 file to pdf with the "courier new" font during the execution of a java web application, but the "courier new" font never shows.

I'm using eclipse luna, ubuntu 14.04 and ireport-5.6.0 .

I have already downloaded all the font files: normal, bold, italic and bold-italic.

I can see the font during the report desing, the problem is at the printing moment.

What should I do?

Comment: You need to use font-extensions, see these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534238/jasperreports-does-not-generate-report-with-bold/,

Comment: Are you using ireport or jaspersoft studio?, there are 2 post by Alex on how to include them in IDE this is for [ireport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport) and this [studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232826/when-export-a-report-to-pdf-change-the-font/)

Comment: @PetterFriberg I'm using jaspersoft ireport designer 5.6.0

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thanks for your answer. Problem solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper ireport 3.7.6 font style not rendering in PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808348/jasper-ireport-3-7-6-font-style-not-rendering-in-pdf)

Comment: Great I have purposed a duplicate consider to accept it.